# Incontinuity in straight segment of wand's polyline

Tags: python, polyline, wand

I'm trying to draw some polylines with wand (v0.6.7), and I've ran across a problem that can be reproduced by running this reduced example.

```
from wand.image import Image
from wand.drawing import Drawing
from wand.color import Color

points= [(1, 171), (1, 15), (31, 15), (31, 7), (21, 7), (21, 17)]

with Drawing() as draw:
    draw.stroke_color = Color('white')
    draw.stroke_width = 1
    draw.fill_color = Color('red')
    draw.fill_opacity = 1
    draw.polyline(points)
    with Image(width=33, height=173, background=Color('black')) as image:
        draw(image)
        image.save(filename ='polyline.png')
```

The resulting image:

[image]

The black pixel around the middle of the left white edge does not make any sense to me. Is this a bug? Or some kind of a side effect of my stroke parameters? It suddenly does disappear if I move the specific segment to the right, so I suspect it is somehow caused by the segment being too close to the edge of the image. Although the same problem does not appear if that's the only segment I try to draw.

Comment: Looks like a bug with ImageMagick. The black pixel is present when running the CLI command: `convert -size 33x173 xc:black -fill red -stroke white -draw 'polyline 1,171 1,15 31,15 31,7 21,7 21,17' polyline.png`

Comment: @emcconville, if you post this as an answer, I'm going to accept it. Thanks for the help!

Comment: This was fixed. See https://github.com/ImageMagick/ImageMagick/issues/4837

Answer (score 0):

I get these "artifacts" randomly when I try to use ImageMagick to do pixel-perfect images. A solution that works for me is to put

```
img.antialias=False
```

just before and just after the draw command.

This way I am able to draw a 1 pixel line without shattered pixels around it.

I think they are remains from some internal image conversion.